# Speech Recognition all english words automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition

I have a windows form application. I want to make a `Voice Recognition`. The problem is the `Grammar` i used is limited from my choices list (see the program below). I want to my program be able to recognise all words.

```
Choices sList = new Choices();
sList.Add(new string[] { "hello", "test", "it works", "how", "are", "you", "today", "i", "am", "fine", "exit", "close", "quit", "so" });
    Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));
```

Do you know how can i make my program recognise all words ?

### Source code :

**Declaration :**

```
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
```

**Program :**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Enabled = false; // Start record
    button3.Enabled = true;  // Stop record
    Choices sList = new Choices();
    sList.Add(new string[] { "hello", "test", "it works", "how", "are", "you", "today", "i", "am", "fine", "exit", "close", "quit", "so" });
    Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));
    try
    {
        sRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        sRecognize.LoadGrammar(gr);
        sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized ;
        sRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        sRecognize.Recognize();
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }
 }

private void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Text == "exit")
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString(); 
    }

}
```

The problem with this program don't recognise all words, and for my project i want to make it recognise all words.

Thanks Stackoverflowers

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, what you mean, this should exactly be what you need:
Simply use a SpeechRecognitionEngine in DictationMode, that way words are recognized (see for example http://csharp-tricks-en.blogspot.de/2011/03/speech-recognition-part-1-dictation-mode.html)